# add a preview of react page when sharing it

Tags: reactjs

I've react application built using react.js and have multiple blogs each blog have its own thumbnail and I want when share one of these blogs to Linkedin or Facebook I want to have a preview link with blog's thumbnail, for example check this preview link
[image]

I've tried react-helmet but didn't work

```js
            <Helmet>
                <meta property="og:title" content="E-Hisba | Calculator" />
                <meta property="og:description" content="Commisionn Calculator for all merchants!" />
                <meta property="og:image" content={embeddedImageUrl} />
                <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content={embeddedImageUrl} />
                <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpg" />
                <meta property="og:image:width" content="1200" />
                <meta property="og:image:height" content="630" />
                <meta property="og:url" content={window.location.href} />
            </Helmet>
```

Comment: Not 100% sure, but many crawlers don't execute js. You'll have to modify the server to respond with appropriate meta data tags

Answer (score 1):

I also use react-helmet for the frontend projects if I don't use Nextjs. It is a good solution. However, there's an important detail about social media sharing that might be causing your issues. When you share a link on a platform like Facebook or LinkedIn, the website's crawler (a bot that explores web content) will fetch your URL to extract meta tags. These crawlers do not execute JavaScript, and since your React application (including react-helmet) is client-side JavaScript, the crawlers will not see any dynamically injected meta tags. This means that the previews you expect won't be created as intended.

To solve this issue, you need to have these tags **statically** served from the server side, which implies a **Server-Side Rendering (SSR)** or a static site generation approach.

For Server-Side Rendering, Next.js can be very helpful. Next.js allows you to render your React pages on the server, which can include the meta tags in the initial server response.

In a Next.js setup, you would use the next/head module to set your meta tags, similar to how you use react-helmet. It would look something like this:

```
import Head from 'next/head';

export default function BlogPost() {
  const title = "E-Hisba | Calculator";
  const description = "Commission Calculator for all merchants!";
  const imageUrl = '...'; // URL of your image
  const url = '...'; // URL of your page

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>{title}</title>
        <meta name="description" content={description} />
        <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
        <meta name="og:title" property="og:title" content={title} />
        <meta name="og:description" property="og:description" content={description} />
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="Site Name" />
        <meta property="og:url" content={`${url}`} />  
        <meta name="og:image" property="og:image" content={imageUrl} />  
      </Head>
      ...
    </>
  );
}
```

This will work with most crawlers, including Facebook's and LinkedIn's.

Comment: Alaikom Salam Brother,

unfortunately the project is on production and switch to next.js now is not available option, any advice?

Comment: I don't have enough information snd experience. I hope this article (SSR with pure react) helps: https://medium.com/swlh/moving-your-website-to-server-side-rendering-ssr-in-reactjs-36278d4a87f5